# Windows 8 VPN disconnects after 10 minutes with Error 829 (ERROR LINK FAILURE)

Tags: networking, windows-8, router, vpn, ppp

My windows VPN (PPTP protocol) **simply disconnects if inactive for 10 MINUTES** (on the spot!). Used this for years on the same computer / system.
Changed MODEM/ROUTER recently (2 months ago) but can't say if the problem started right after... My ISP says can't be the modem...

RASMON says the following: **Completely disconnected connection: Reason: ERROR_LINK_FAILURE (829)**

Microsoft says: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773767(v=ws.10).aspx
Error 829 (ERROR_LINK_FAILURE)
Message: The modem (or other connecting device) was disconnected due to link failure. *This error appears when the modem (in the case of dial-up or broadband connections) or tunnel (in the case of VPN connections) is disconnected due to a network failure or a failure in the physical link to the modem.*

Any ideas? Going nuts with this one... started a few weeks ago... uninstalled all the 2017 windows 8.1 updates to be sure it was not an update change (it is not!)

Comment: Have you talked to your VPN provider? Their server may be timing out due to a setting they implemented.

Comment: This is definitely a time-out issue. It could absolutely be related to your new ISP Modem depending on how long it will keep an idle entry in it’s NAT/Firewall table. You need to talk with your VPN provider and find out how to enable “keep alives.” This will prevent the connection from timing out by sending some data periodically.

Comment: The VPN provider (server) it's ok... all other clients have no issues...